# Can PhpStorm recognize function pointers?

Tags: php, phpstorm

## The Setup

I use a lot of function pointers in my PHP code and some functions are called only by function pointer. A simple and common example that may relate to others:

```
// Stub of my custom assert failure function.
function assertFailure($file, $line, $code, $message = '')
{
  http_response_code(500);
  echo '<h1>ASSERT FAILURE: </h1>';
  // ...
  die();
}

assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'assertFailure');
```

## The problem

PhpStorm is flagging these functions as "not used" as they are used only in function pointers. I like the inspection as it has helped me clean up a lot of old code. So I don't want to turn it off completely.

## The question(s)

1. How do I get PhpStorm to recognize the function is used or at least inline disable the inspection for a specific function? I occasionally use lines that allow me to disable an inspection for specific use case such as a missing break in a switch: `/** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */`. I can not find an equivalent for this.
2. An even better solution would be for PhpStorm to recognize the string as a function pointer so I could jump to definition, check parameter lists, and it would know I was using it. Is there a setting or a comment declaration I can use similar to identifying variable types `/** @var DateTime $now */`.

Comment: Some inspections can be suppressed selectively, but it doesn't look like this is one ofthem.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813465/php-variable-function-name-called-how-to-tell-ide-my-function-is-called

Comment: @Barmar excellent find. This may be a duplicate now. I was searching for "function pointer" so that solution did not appear for me.

Comment: `/** @uses assertFailure() */` on top of `assert_options()` call seems to work fine.

Comment: It's not a general solution, since function references can be used from places you don't have control over, like `array_map('funcName', $some_array);`

Comment: @Barmar true but usually functions that are pointed to are designed as function pointers to be called from 1 or 2 global locations. So having a long running list of all the functions callable from a single location is feasible, despite being a bit of a headache.

Comment: @Barmar It's certainly not as nice as IDE magic but it does work, doesn't it? You just need to put `/** @uses funcName() */` right before `array_map('funcName', $some_array);` (or, probably, anywhere in your codebase.)